# make div(td) to be link. haml (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml

i have a problem. i have table. and i want to make td in table to be a links

i was trying to do like this

```
=link_to " ", message
  %td    
    From:
    =link_to message.sender.name,message.sender
    %br
    Theme:
    =message.theme
    %br
    Content:
    =message.content
```

but it writes an error

> syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

but i dont know about what "end" it is talking about.
So how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using tables and BRs? Could you not use divs, this becomes much simpler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) you can do this:

```
=link_to message do
  %td    
    From:
    =link_to message.sender.name,message.sender
    %br
    Theme:
    =message.theme
    %br
    Content:
    =message.content
```

which should yield markup like this:

```
<a href="messages/4">
  <td>From: <a href="/senders/4">John</a><br><br/>Theme: nicetheme<br></br>Content: Blablabla</td>
</a>
```

This is AFAIK not valid HTML. So you might want to do this:

```
%td
  =link_to message do      
    From:
    =link_to message.sender.name,message.sender
    %br
    Theme:
    =message.theme
    %br
    Content:
    =message.content
```

Comment: i made like you said , it have no errors, but it just did empty link before table like <a href="http://localhost:3000/messages"></a> , but i want put <td> into <a>(

Comment: i made like you said in your edit , it makes <a href="localhost:3000/messages"> From</a> in the begining of each td, not all td in link

Comment: ahh , i found why, it is cause i have link_to in link, that's why. Thanks for help!!!

Comment: <a><td></td></a> is valid HTML5 now.